# create table in oracle from operations on columns in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (say table_1) having some columns of type number. Now i want to create other table (say table_2) having columns (name, sum, avg,  max, min) which will store computed value of columns from the table_1.

Right now i'm creating table_2 and then inserting row in table_2 for each column in table_1 one at a time.

I want to do this in a single statement update. Query Like: "Create table_2(name, sum, avg, ...) select ....".
Please help me creating the execute statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an UNPIVOT operation.

```
SELECT colname, SUM(value), AVG(value), MIN(value), MAX(value)
  FROM table1
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR colname IN (x,y,..) )
  GROUP BY colname
```

Where "x,y,..." should be the actual column names in your source table.

**Edited to add**

In pre-11g versions of Oracle, you can roll your own unpivot.  Example for two columns:

```
WITH driver AS (
  SELECT level colnum FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 2
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN colnum=1 THEN 'x' WHEN colnum=2 THEN 'y' END colname,
  CASE WHEN colnum=1 THEN sum_x WHEN colnum=2 THEN sum_y END colsum,
  CASE WHEN colnum=1 THEN avg_x WHEN colnum=2 THEN avg_y END colavg
FROM driver
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(x) sum_x, AVG(x) avg_x, SUM(y) sum_y, AVG(y) avg_y
    FROM mytable
  )
ORDER BY colnum
```

Comment: i'm using 10g version of oracle.

Answer (score 0):

That's legitimate: you can do

```
CREATE TABLE myTable as

SELECT....
;
```

or even using a common table expression:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable as
WITH myCte as
(
    SELECT....
)
SELECT....
;
```

Comment: yeah i know :) but how to compute sum, avg.. etc for every column in table_1 in a single statement to put it in table_2.

Comment: That's a bit difficult without knowing how exactly you are defining your aggregates: if you want a "rolling" aggregate (i.e. relevant only for rows *already* present in the table), then you can use analytic functions to calculate a min/max over all rows with a smaller ID.